# can i make a two dimensional table in django-tables2?

Tags: python, django, html-table, django-templates, django-tables2

Edited:
Hi guys, I have been looking for a solution to my problem for some days without an answer
I am trying to make a two-dimensional table with data obtained from the same model.
The idea is to list the students in rows, the data in columns and the status in their respective cells, a two dimensional table.

```
class DailyAttendanceStudent(models.Model):
    ATTENDANCE_CHOICES = (
        (None,''),
        (True,'Presente'),
        (False, 'Ausente')
        )
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    status = models.NullBooleanField(choices=ATTENDANCE_CHOICES)
    student = models.ForeignKey('perfiles.Student')
```

These are my table:

```
class StudentAttendanceTable(tables.Table):
    nombres = tables.Column('nombres', accessor='Student.first_name')
    apellidos = tables.Column('apellidos', accessor='Student.last_name')
    date = tables.Column('fecha', accessor='date')#LinkColumn
    status = tables.Column('status', accessor='status')
    class Meta:
        model = DailyAttendanceStudent
        fields = ('nombres', 'apellidos', 'date', 'status')
```

graphically this is what I want to do:

[image: I want to do this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would do something like this:

- Filter the `DailyAttendanceStudent` queryset like desired, and pass it to your table.
- Implement a custom constructor for your table, doing something like this:

  - Loop over the queryset, transforming it to a [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) with the user id as key. For any new date you should add a new column to the instance, and add a key for that date to the OrderedDict.
  - The new column can be a `table.Column`, or something specialized to suit your needs.
  - The custom constructor should call the constructor of the parent class, passing the items of the OrderedDict as data and the date columns as `extra_columns`.

In code, it could look like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import django_tables2 as tables

class StudentAttendanceTable(tables.Table):
    nombres = tables.Column('nombres', accessor='student.first_name')
    apellidos = tables.Column('apellidos', accessor='student.last_name')

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        rows = OrderedDict()
        extra_columns = {}
        for row in data:
            if row.student.id not in rows:
                rows[row.student.id] = {'student': row.student}
            rows[row.student.id][row.date] = row.status
            extra_columns[row.date.isoformat()] = tables.Column()  # use more specialized column if you get this to work
        super(StudentAttendanceTable, self).__init__(data=rows.values(), extra_columns=extra_columns.items(), *args, **kwargs)
```

You might want to sort the value you pass to `extra_columns`, as the order retrieved from the database might not be the desired order for presentation.

Comment: I was very helpful your comment, but to be honest, I could not populate the table with the status. It would be useful to have a tutorial on django tables2 on two-dimensional tables or pivot tables. I found more questions than answers on the web.
Your answer was the one that helped me the most, the problem is that I need to study more about django :D